# sqlalchemy: prevent relationship objects from being added to session automatically

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a python script that creates some SQLAlchemy objects, checks which of those objects have already been added to the database and then adds any new objects. My script looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

# Define models
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Person"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    pets = relationship("Pet", backref="person")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Person: {self.name}>"


class Pet(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Pet"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Person.id"))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Pet: {self.name}>"

connection_string = "sqlite:///db.sqlite3"
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
session = Session(
    bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False, autoflush=False, autocommit=False
)

# Build tables
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create data
persons = [
    Person(name="Johnny"),
    Person(name="Steph"),
]

pets = [
    Pet(name="Packets", person=persons[0]),
    Pet(name="Sally", person=persons[1]),
    Pet(name="Shiloh", person=persons[0]),
]

# Populate tables with data
for items in [persons, pets]:
    for item in items:
        q = session.query(item.__class__).filter_by(name=item.name).one_or_none()
        if q:
            print(f"Already exists: {item}")
            continue
        session.add(item)
        session.commit()
        print(f"Added: {item}")
```

When I run it, I get the following result:

```
Added: <Person: Johnny>
Added: <Person: Steph>
Already exists: <Pet: Packets>
Already exists: <Pet: Sally>
Already exists: <Pet: Shiloh>
```

I would expect the result to look like this:

```
Added: <Person: Johnny>
Added: <Person: Steph>
Added: <Pet: Packets>
Added: <Pet: Sally>
Added: <Pet: Shiloh>
```

What's happening that's adding the `Pet` objects before they're actually added to the session? How can I prevent this so my output is as expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's happening that's adding the `Pet` objects before they're
>   actually added to the session?

Inserting `<Person: Johnny>` implicitly inserts `<Pet: Packets>` and `<Pet: Shiloh>`; inserting `<Person: Steph>` implicitly inserts `<Pet: Sally>`.

That's because `backref` creates a bidirectional relationship.
As described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref) in the docs:

> [...] when the [`backref`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.backref) keyword is used on a single relationship, it’s
>   exactly the same as if [...] two relationships were created
>   individually using [`back_populates`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates) [...]

You create `Pet` instances that relate to `Person` instances, that do not yet exist in the database. With the default cascading settings, that leads to the implicit inserts of the related objects to represent both directions of the relationship.

This can be observed by creating the engine with `echo` set to `True`:

```
engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)
```

This enables base engine output:

```
# Time stamps and log level omitted for brevity
# First iteration of the loop (Johnny):
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "Person" (name) VALUES (?)
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('Johnny',)
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "Pet" (name, person_id) VALUES (?, ?)
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('Packets', 1)
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "Pet" (name, person_id) VALUES (?, ?)
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('Shiloh', 1)
# Second iteration of the loop (Steph):
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "Person" (name) VALUES (?)
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('Steph',)
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "Pet" (name, person_id) VALUES (?, ?)
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('Sally', 2)
# Third to fifth iteration: the Pets already exist.
```

The other way round is similar; if you specify the pet list first, your output looks like this:

```
Added: <Pet: Packets>            # implicitly creates Person Johnny and, through Johnny, Pet Shiloh
Added: <Pet: Sally>              # implicitly creates Person Steph
Already exists: <Pet: Shiloh>    
Already exists: <Person: Johnny>
Already exists: <Person: Steph>
```

As Ilja Everilä pointed out in the comments, the simplest way to disable the implicit insertion of the Pets is to remove the [`save-update`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html#save-update) setting from the relationship's [`cascades`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html):

```
pets = relationship("Pet", backref="person", cascade="merge")
```

Note, that issues a warning:

> SAWarning: Object of type `<Pet>` not in session, add operation along
>   `Person.pets` will not proceed

A more verbose way to prevent the pets from being created implicitly through the relationship, is to postpone their instantiation until after the persons have been inserted, e.g.:

```
# Don't instantiate just yet
# pets = [
#     Pet(name="Packets", person=persons[0]),
#     Pet(name="Sally", person=persons[1]),
#     Pet(name="Shiloh", person=persons[0]),
# ]

pets = {persons[0]: ['Packets', 'Shiloh'],
        persons[1]: ['Sally']}

for item in persons:
    if session.query(item.__class__).filter_by(name=item.name).one_or_none():
        print(f"Already exists: {item}")
        continue
    session.add(item)
    session.commit()
    print(f"Added: {item}")
    for pet in pets[item]:
        p = Pet(name=pet, person=item)
        session.add(p)
        session.commit()
        print(f"Added: {p}")
```

Output:

```
Added: <Person: Johnny>
Added: <Pet: Packets>
Added: <Pet: Shiloh>
Added: <Person: Steph>
Added: <Pet: Sally>
```

However, with the default behavior, you can effectively omit the explicit insertion of the Pets. Just iterating `persons`, will insert all Pet instances as well; three unnecessary queries are skipped.

Comment: Another option would be to alter the cascade configuration (disable save-update) of the relationships, though usually the defaults are ok: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html